# What does it mean when a PS4 game says PS4 PRO ENHANCED on the cover?

Tags: ps4

While going though my collectors editions making sure I got everything and if there was any bonus DLC I noticed on *God Wars: Future Past* on the back there was an icon with the other icons which tell you how many players are supported, HDD Space, Remote Play being available. this icon said PS4 PRO ENHANCED

[image: Icon]

checking some of my other games *Nier: Automata* has this icon but *Gravity Rush 2* doesn't and *Nier: Automata* was release just a bit over a month after Gravity Rush. (Nier = February 23, 2017, Gravity Rush 2 = January 18, 2017)

Now while I could assume this would mean that *Nier: Automata* needs the PS4 Pro Enhanced to play but I know this is wrong as my PS4 is the first generation model and *Nier: Automata* plays perfectly fine.

So what does it mean when a PS4 game says PS4 PRO ENHANCED on the cover?

Comment: *enhance*... click clack click clack ...*enhance*... click clack click clack ...*enhance*... click clack click clack ...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"*PS4 Pro Enhanced*" simply means that the game makes use of the improved performance that the PS4 Pro offers. In other words: the game offers improvements when played on the Pro.

What those improvements are depends on the game. Most of the time, games will offer improved performance or graphical quality.

*Horizon Zero Dawn* for instance, lets players choose between either improved resolution or improved performance. *Nier Automata* on the other hand increases resolution to Full HD (1080p) and manages to keep framerates more consistent at the same time.

Games that are not "Pro Enhanced" do not offer any improvements when played on the Pro. *Persona 5* for instance renders exactly the same on PS4 and PS4 Pro; same framerate, same resolution, same graphics quality. Please note that Pro Enhancement can be patched in (e.g. *Uncharted 4* and *Infamous*), so even if it doesn't say "PS4 Pro Enhanced" on the cover, the game can still offer improvements after installing recent updates.

For games that are not "enhanced", the PS4 Pro also offers a "Boost Mode" which simply improves performance for games (if possible) in exchange for possibly causing issues.

Comment: Do you have to turn this boost mode on explicitly or does the PS4 Pro do this automatically?

Comment: @Chris, you have to turn it on explicitly. Since it can cause problems with (poorly written) games that rely on the regular PS4's clock speeds for timing, it's an option that can be turned on or off. I've not yet experienced any issues with it, though.

Comment: Certain games might not have a notice on the box for enhanced performance; CD Projekt Red is working on patches for The Witcher 3, but likely the original box art won't have this notice.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? PS4 Pro is capable of 4K, yet you claim that *Nier Automata* increases to only 1080p and requires the Pro to do that?

Comment: @Octopus 4K video. I seem to remember talk of games not going up that high.

Comment: the PS4 Pro is only capabale of 4K with certain checkboarding techniques, and many games don't yet run at 1080p on the main system. The Pro is closer to the Xbox One S than the Xbox One X. The improvement is not massive. (I actually guess that Microsoft added the S only after finding out about the Pro, to be able to compete on price.)

Comment: @Octopus. According to [Digital Foundry](https://www.digitalfoundry.net/2017-02-27-nier-automata-ps4-vs-ps4-pro-final-code-analysis), Nier Automata runs in 900p on the regular PS4, and 1080p on the Pro. Cutscenes remain in 900p on both. I'm sure the game could run at a higher resolution on the Pro, but the devs decided not to.